# How to do a variable jump height based on how long key is held in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have no idea how to do this using the get_pressed() method with Pygame. I also messed around with the event key pressed too but wasn't having much success.

Here is a basic outline of a get_pressed jump from Tech with Tim to get started: https://www.ideone.com/ypS334

import pygame

```
pygame.init()
 
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
 
x = 50
y = 250
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5
 
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
 
run = True
 
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
 
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
 
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - vel - width:
        x += vel
 
    if not (isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False
 
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
 
pygame.quit()
```

How can we take this a set it up to A) detect when the key is let go and B) to start descending immediately when it is. Also should probably have a height limit for how high it can jump. Most resources, websites, and videos either just say how to get an object to jump or its for a different language. Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: You need to browse the package documentation to learn its facilities.  All you need for your application is to mark the `time.time()` difference from KEYDOWN to KEYUP.

Answer (score 3):

Add a variable `jumpCountMax` instead of the constant 10.

```py
jumpCountMax = 10
jumpCount = jumpCountMax
```

Use the `KEYDONW` and `KEYUP` event instead of `keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:`. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) to measure the time between `KEYDONW` and `KEYUP`. Set `jumpCountMax` depending on the time and start the jump when <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is released (`KEYUP`):

```py
while run:
    # [...]
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not isJump:
                sp_start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
             if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not isJump:
                sp_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - sp_start
                jumpCountMax = min(12, sp_time // 40) 
                jumpCount = jumpCountMax 
                isJump = True

        # [...]
```

Play around with the constants in `min(12, sp_time // 40)`, to meet your needs.

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
x, y, width, height, vel = 50, 250,40, 60, 5
 
isJump = False
jumpCountMax = 10
jumpCount = jumpCountMax

run = True 
while run:
    clock.tick(20)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not isJump:
                sp_start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
             if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and not isJump:
                sp_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - sp_start
                jumpCountMax = min(12, sp_time // 40) 
                jumpCount = jumpCountMax 
                isJump = True
 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - vel - width:
        x += vel
 
    if isJump:
        if jumpCount >= -jumpCountMax:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = jumpCountMax
            isJump = False
 
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
 
pygame.quit()
```